Cant able to build the blender
CMake Error at third_party/CMakeLists.txt:33 (message): gmock was not found - required for tests

i downloaded the gmock and try to build
CMake Error at third_party/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package): By not providing "FindGMock.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "GMock", but CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GMock" with any of the following names:

GMockConfig.cmake
gmock-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "GMock" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "GMock_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "GMock" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.

I installed gmock manually then also i am facing this error

Have you done the steps on the last line, i.e. added GMock to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, or set GMock_DIR?

yeah I done but still facing that error
